# Registering custom vega formatters in jupyterlab with altair

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, altair, vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to implement a custom formatter *formatType* that I can use with altair in jupyterlab. I cannot figure out how to register the vega expression function in jupyterlab. It works when using the vega-editor and injecting the expression using the JS console. How to register the expression function from a jupyterlab cell?

Using the definition generated by

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

def pub_theme():
    return {'config': {"customFormatTypes": True}}
alt.themes.register('pub', pub_theme)
alt.themes.enable('pub')

alt.Chart(
    pd.DataFrame({'x': [1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 1e10], 'y':[1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 1e10]})
).mark_line(
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q'),
    x=alt.X('x:Q', axis=alt.Axis(formatType='pubformat'))
)
```

and [opening the definition in the Vega-lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlGArgZwC4QLYBiEATngIbYAqAngA4CmmK2x69ANCAEZlgDWCYhHRQAJihAsyUTLTLF6UbCAC+nURTIpQUMnnoSN2MgFoAnADYyAVgAMAdgBMZmE8dcAzABYwARjNgXI7W9AAcMC62FqK+Bmog5MR8EgA2cFAGnIqQoulIqCAAHtqSdAbIIACO6NLYcMZ1AG6ZIGSFcEwFMCTkVGUStOhc3aQUqpzw9CniFcXx1CXY-RXVtfUUcM0gE3BTMyALKvEAJJhgABb05BLn2Ni0mMgA9E-NCGQAdAj150MfcBAnmdLuRXvR3iY0th6K8vB9Qh9fB8AFaYaDbEBGMiYejYTqgLHmKx2JwuNyeHz+QLBMIRGBRGLlADaoGKyFsH1stl8nAW7M53LUrJQHO5vJFnN8QqKKB5B1l0rZvi5KtVtnFyGVatVKgAukcgA) gives as expected `[Error] Unrecognized function: pubformat`

If `pubformat` is defined via the JS console witg e.g. `VEGA_DEBUG.vega.expressionFunction('pubformat', function() {return 'test'})`, then the editor produces the expected output with 6 identical labels `test`  on the x axis.

What is the correct way to achieve this within jupyterlab?

Injecting the expression `vega.expressionFunction('pubformat', function() {return 'test'})`from the JS console on the jupyterlab page doesn't work. Defining it via

```
from IPython.display import HTML
    HTML("""
        <script>
            vega.expressionFunction('pubformat', function() {return 'test'})
        </script>
     """)
```

didn't work neither.

If injecting javascript is an issue, are there any other options for implementing a custom formatter in altair? It seems that a similar behavior can be achieve using `labelExpr` on the axis, however this is less generic, as the expression must be repeated for each axis. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom formatters in Vega-Lite were added in [version 4.11](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/releases/tag/v4.11.0); Altair currently supports [Vega-Lite v4.8.1](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/blob/d862ad494ecc0a5cff7e8b114df14e0796efa108/altair/vegalite/v4/schema/__init__.py#L4), so custom formatters are not supported by the current release of Altair.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use `labelExpr` . I could achieve the desired behavior using

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

def pub_theme():
    return {'config': {"axis": {"labelExpr": "replace(datum.label, datum.label, 'test')"}}}
alt.themes.register('pub', pub_theme)
alt.themes.enable('pub')

alt.Chart(
    pd.DataFrame({'x': [1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 1e10], 'y':[1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 1e10]})
).mark_line(
).encode(
    y=alt.Y('y:Q'),
    x=alt.X('x:Q')
)
```